# the link of the product tab appears 2 characters /

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using WCFM plugin. Everything works fine, there is only one problem that I have not solved yet, that is the link of the product tab appearing 2 // characters, and it is wrong with some other functions on my web.
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQgTs.png)

all other tabs are fine, only the product tab appears 2 characters / as below.

ex: mydomain.com/store/storename//#tab_links_area

And I want it to turn into the following

mydomain.com/store/storename/#tab_links_area

or: mydomain.com/store/storename/product/#tab_links_area

And I have checked that the code that affects this place is in store-tabs.php file of WCFM plugin as follows

```html
<?php do_action( 'wcfmmp_store_before_tabs', $store_user->get_id() ); ?>

<div id="tab_links_area" class="tab_links_area">
    <ul class="tab_links">
      <?php foreach( $store_tabs as $store_tab_key => $store_tab_label ) { ?>
        <li class="<?php if( $store_tab_key == $store_tab ) echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $store_user->get_store_tabs_url( $store_tab_key ); ?>/#tab_links_area"><?php echo $store_tab_label; ?></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="wcfm-clearfix"></div>

<?php do_action( 'wcfmmp_store_after_tabs', $store_user->get_id() ); ?>
```

I don't know anything about code, can you help me fix this issue using CSS or using code to insert to function.php in my child theme.
I am very grateful and look forward to your feedback

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the store link is register with a "**/**" at the end in the database whereas the others are not. Maybe there was a change in the permalink structure between the creation of product page and the other pages.
First thing you can do is to go to **settings->permalinks** and click the "**save changes**" to make sure all your links will have the same structure.

If this not solve your issue, you can handle it with your code.
You can test if the last caracter of the string that contains your pages link "*$store_user->get_store_tabs_url( $store_tab_key )*" end up with a "/" and if it the case delete it before it is used in the anchor tag.

So, in those lines =>

```html
<?php foreach( $store_tabs as $store_tab_key => $store_tab_label ) { ?>
  <li class="<?php if( $store_tab_key == $store_tab ) echo 'active'; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $store_user->get_store_tabs_url( $store_tab_key ); ?>/#tab_links_area"><?php echo $store_tab_label; ?></a>   
  </li>
<?php } ?>
```

you should add the test and have something like that :

```
<?php foreach( $store_tabs as $store_tab_key => $store_tab_label ) { ?>
    <li class="<?php if( $store_tab_key == $store_tab ) echo 'active'; ?>">
        <?php 
            /* Get the link */
            $tab_link = $store_user->get_store_tabs_url( $store_tab_key );
            /* If the link end up with "/" */
            if(substr($tab_link, -1) == "/"){ 
                $tab_link = substr_replace($tab_link ,"",-1); // Delete the last caracter. 
            }
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $tab_link ?>/#tab_links_area"><?php echo $store_tab_label; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Antoine, thanks for your advice but can i use the code to insert in my function.php without editing it directly in the plugin's tabs.php file? Because when the plugin is updated this may happen again

Comment: The structure of other link tabs is as follows ( ex: mydomain.com/store/storename/about/#tab_links_area ). If I omit the / ending character then there is a problem with the other link tabs. it becomes: mydomain.com/store/storenameabout/#tab_links_area